# Issue of updating GAE python application

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

When updating my app into GAE by using the following command:
python appcfg.py update /home/tom/workspace/DjangoProject

I got an error message:

```
mapping values are not allowed here
  in "/home/tom/workspace/DjangoProject/app.yaml", line 6, column 9
```

Here is my yaml:

```
application:myapp
version:1
runtime:python
api_version:1

handlers:
- url:/
  script:home.py

- url:/index\.html
  script: home.py

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))

- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.py
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: not_found.py
```

Can anybody help me?

I changed my yaml:

```
application:myapp
version:1
runtime:python
api_version:1
handlers
- url:/
  script:home.py
- url:/index\.html
  script:home.py
- url:/stylesheets
  static_dir:stylesheets
- url:/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files:static/\1
  upload:static/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
- url:/admin/.*
  script:admin.py
  login:admin
- url:/.*
  script:not_found.py
```

Now the error meesage is :

google.appengine.api.appinfo_errors.MissingURLMapping: No URLMap entries found in application configuration

Comment: I think you need a space after the colons `- url: /` and `- url: /index\.html`

Comment: I think you need spaces after the colons.

Comment: You changed your `app.yaml`... and _removed_ all the spaces, instead of adding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a colon , there has to be space . That's why it was not able to parse your app.yaml.
Try this

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: home.py

- url: /index\.html
  script: home.py

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))

- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.py
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: not_found.py
```